# Inertial desktop browser scrolling

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, parallax

How do I get an easing effect with my browser's scroll? I have a parallax website set up and am trying to achieve something like the following:

[Example](https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT)

```
So I go:

$('window').scroll(function() {


});
```

Comment: So far I haven't been able to find anything to set me in the right direction.

Comment: you need to use jquery animate function on scroll of window .

Comment: I've seen a plugin in that has this feature, but it won't let me retain the appearance of my scrollbar.